# Some programs don't start on Windows 10 with the Nvidia 540m

Tags: windows-10, laptop, nvidia-graphics-card

The 540m it's an old Nvidia chip for laptops, the last driver it's from 2018 tho. I notice recently that some of the programs on my computer, mostly those that are gpu intensive stop working, photoshop, fusion 360 and others.

I can see their process on the task manager but they don't do anything it's like they are waiting for something.

This laptop also have an internal video chip that I can select  instead of the 540m when running applications, in this case they work.

Here's an interesting detail: when running photoshop with the 540m the program attually starts, but when you create a canvas, it freezes. By going to the task manager, then again the program is there doing nothing, but if you open the process details to see the sub process I notice a sniffer_cpu.exe that according to abobe is legit, If I killed tho Photoshop unfreeze and work as intended. So it definetly  something related to the card.

Comment: For Ps, Prefs>Performance, switch off GPU acceleration, top right. Any help?

Comment: @Tetsujin I can lunch PS with GPU acceleration, it works, very slow but it works, it's not ideal of course